# SAS match two datasets by ID and creating an indicator

Tags: merge, sas, set, match

I have these two datasets with a different Item code

```
Data1

ID    Item_Code
101      672
101      672
201      672


Data2

ID    Item_Code
101      075
101      075
401      075
```

I need to create the following Dataset

Want

```
ID    Item_Code    Data1_only  Data2_only Both_Data1_Data2
101      672                                    1
101      672                                    1 
101      075                                    1 
101      075                                    1 
201      672           1
401      075                         1


 Data1_only = Id exists in Data1 only
 Data2_only = Id exists in Data2 only 
 Both_Data1_Data2 = ID Exists in both the datasets
```

I am using the following code

```
Data final;
set Data1 (in=a) and Data2 (in=b);
By id;
  if a and not b then Data1_only=1;
  if b and not a then Data2_only=1;
  if a and b then Both_Data1_Data2=1;
 run;
```

But this is not solving the purpose. I have millions of records in both the dataset and any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A standard `SET` statement, alone in an implicit loop `DATA` step stacks data sets.  You will **not** be able to fathom the second set while reading (and outputting) data from the first dataset.

However, a DOW loop with `SET` and `BY` can iterate over both data sets and compute the desired state flags for a `BY` group.  After group is read the state flags are used to compute the final desired boolean variables.  A *second* DOW applies the the computed result to each row in the *dual sourced* group.

Example:

- Flag variables tacitly reset to missing at top of implicit loop.
- Flag1 and Flag2 are conditionally assigned when `in=` variable asserts true
- Flag1 and Flag2 compute overall group state variable **after** processing group in first loop

```
data Data1; input
ID    Item_Code; datalines;
101      672
101      672
201      672
;

data Data2; input
ID    Item_Code; datalines;
101      075
101      075
401      075
;

Data final;
  do until (last.id);
    set Data1 (in=a) Data2 (in=b);
    by id;
    if a then flag1=a;
    if b then flag2=b;
  end;

  data1_only = flag1 and not flag2;
  data2_only = flag2 and not flag1;
  data1_and_2 = flag1 and flag2;

  do until (last.id);
    set Data1 (in=a) Data2 (in=b);
    by id;
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  drop flag1 flag2;
run;
```